# fread() fails with missing values in integer64 columns

Tags: r, data.table

When reading the text below, `fread()` fails to detect the missing values in columns 8 and 9. This is only with the default option `integer64="integer64"`. Setting `integer64="double"` or `"character"` correctly detects `NA`s. Note that the file has three types of possible NAs in V8 and V9-- `,,`; `, ,`; and `NA`. Appending `na.strings=c("NA","N/A",""," "), sep=","` as options has no effect.

Using `read.csv()` works the same way as `fread(integer="double")`.

Text to be read (also [available as a file integer64_and_NA.csv](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74885015/integer64_and_NA.csv)):

```
2012,276,,0,"S1","001",1,,724135215,1590915056,
2012,276,2,8,"S1","001",1, ,,154598,0
2012,276,2,12,"S1","001",1,NA,5118863,21819477,
2012,276,2,0,"S1","011",8,3127133583,3127133583,9003982501,0
```

Here's the output from `fread()`:

```
DT <- fread(input="integer64_and_NA.csv", verbose=TRUE, integer64="integer64", na.strings=c("NA","N/A",""," "), sep=",")

Input contains no \n. Taking this to be a filename to open
Detected eol as \r\n (CRLF) in that order, the Windows standard.
Looking for supplied sep ',' on line 4 (the last non blank line in the first 'autostart') ... found ok
Found 11 columns
First row with 11 fields occurs on line 1 (either column names or first row of data)
Some fields on line 1 are not type character (or are empty). Treating as a data row and using default column names.
Count of eol after first data row: 5
Subtracted 1 for last eol and any trailing empty lines, leaving 4 data rows
Type codes: 11114412221 (first 5 rows)
Type codes: 11114412221 (after applying colClasses and integer64)
Type codes: 11114412221 (after applying drop or select (if supplied)
Allocating 11 column slots (11 - 0 NULL)
   0.000s (  0%) Memory map (rerun may be quicker)
   0.000s (  0%) sep and header detection
   0.000s (  0%) Count rows (wc -l)
   0.000s (  0%) Column type detection (first, middle and last 5 rows)
   0.000s (  0%) Allocation of 4x11 result (xMB) in RAM
   0.000s (  0%) Reading data
   0.000s (  0%) Allocation for type bumps (if any), including gc time if triggered
   0.000s (  0%) Coercing data already read in type bumps (if any)
   0.000s (  0%) Changing na.strings to NA
   0.001s        Total
```

The resulting data.table is:

```
DT
     V1  V2 V3 V4 V5  V6 V7                  V8                  V9        V10 V11
1: 2012 276 NA  0 S1 001  1 9218868437227407266           724135215 1590915056  NA
2: 2012 276  2  8 S1 001  1 9218868437227407266 9218868437227407266     154598   0
3: 2012 276  2 12 S1 001  1 9218868437227407266             5118863   21819477  NA
4: 2012 276  2  0 S1 011  8          3127133583          3127133583 9003982501   0
```

`NA` values are properly detected in columns which are not `integer64`. For V8 and V9, which `fread()` marks as integer64, instead of NAs we have "9218868437227407266".
Interestingly enough, `str()` returns the respective values of V8 and V9 as `NA`:

```
str(DT)

Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ V1 : int  2012 2012 2012 2012
 $ V2 : int  276 276 276 276
 $ V3 : int  NA 2 2 2
 $ V4 : int  0 8 12 0
 $ V5 : chr  "S1" "S1" "S1" "S1"
 $ V6 : chr  "001" "001" "001" "011"
 $ V7 : int  1 1 1 8
 $ V8 :Class 'integer64'  num [1:4] NA NA NA 1.55e-314
 $ V9 :Class 'integer64'  num [1:4] 3.58e-315 NA 2.53e-317 1.55e-314
 $ V10:Class 'integer64'  num [1:4] 7.86e-315 7.64e-319 1.08e-316 4.45e-314
 $ V11: int  NA 0 NA 0
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

... but nothing else sees them as `NA`:

```
is.na(DT$V8)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
max(DT$V8)
integer64
[1] 9218868437227407266
> max(DT$V8, na.rm=TRUE)
integer64
[1] 9218868437227407266
> class(DT$V8)
[1] "integer64"
> typeof(DT$V8)
[1] "double"
```

It does not seem to be a print/screen issue only, `data.table` sees them as huge integers:

```
DT[, V12:=as.numeric(V8)]
Warning message:
In as.double.integer64(V8) :
  integer precision lost while converting to double
> DT
     V1  V2 V3 V4 V5  V6 V7                  V8                  V9        V10 V11          V12
1: 2012 276 NA  0 S1 001  1 9218868437227407266           724135215 1590915056  NA 9.218868e+18
2: 2012 276  2  8 S1 001  1 9218868437227407266 9218868437227407266     154598   0 9.218868e+18
3: 2012 276  2 12 S1 001  1 9218868437227407266             5118863   21819477  NA 9.218868e+18
4: 2012 276  2  0 S1 011  8          3127133583          3127133583 9003982501   0 3.127134e+09
```

Am I missing something about `integer64`, or is this a bug? As said above, I can get around using `integer64="double"`, possibly losing some precision, as mentioned in the help file. But the unexpected behavior is with the default `integer64`...

This was done on a Windows 8.1 64-bit machine running Revolution R 3.0.2, and also on a virtual machine running kubuntu 13.10, CRAN-R 3.0.2.  Tested with the latest stable data.table from CRAN (1.8.10 as of 7 Feb 2014) and 1.8.11 (rev. 1110, 2014-02-04 02:43:19, manually installed from the zip as the r-forge build is broken) on Windows, and only the stable 1.8.10 on linux. bit64 is installed and loaded on both machines.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] bit64_0.9-3       bit_1.1-11        gdata_2.13.2      xts_0.9-7         zoo_1.7-10        nlme_3.1-113      hexbin_1.26.3     lattice_0.20-24   ggplot2_0.9.3.1  
[10] plyr_1.8          reshape2_1.2.2    data.table_1.8.11 Revobase_7.0.0    RevoMods_7.0.0    RevoScaleR_7.0.0 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] codetools_0.2-8    colorspace_1.2-4   dichromat_2.0-0    digest_0.6.4       foreach_1.4.1      gtable_0.1.2       gtools_3.2.1       iterators_1.0.6   
 [9] labeling_0.2       MASS_7.3-29        munsell_0.4.2      proto_0.3-10       RColorBrewer_1.0-5 reshape_0.8.4      scales_0.2.3       stringr_0.6.2     
[17] tools_3.0.2
```

Comment: From the help page, "This function is still under development."  So I expect the author will take this up as a bug

Comment: Disappointed this hasn't been addressed yet; it makes the bit64 package useless with data.tables if there's any missing values. I think the issue must be with `fread`, because I can't find any way to force the bit64 package to produce that value. It has a perfectly valid NA value; `as.integer64(NA)  # <NA>`

Comment: See the related bug, https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/488

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This apparently is an issue with the bit64 package, not `fread()` or `data.table`.  From the `bit64` documentation http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bit64/bit64.pdf

"Subscripting non-existing elements and subscripting with NAs is currently not supported. Such subscripting currently returns 9218868437227407266 instead of NA (the NA value of the un-derlying double code). Following the full R behaviour here would either destroy performance or require extensive C-coding."

I tried reassigning the 9218868437227407266 value to NA thinking it would work

Ex.

```
DT[V8==9218868437227407266, ]
#actually returns nothing, but
DT[V8==max(V8), ]
#returns the rows with 9218868437227407266 in V8
#but this does not reassign the value 
DT[V8==max(V8), V8:=NA]
#not that this makes sense, but I tried just in case...
DT[V8==max(V8), V8:=NA_character_]
```

So as the documentation pretty clearly states, if a vector is class integer64 it won't recognize NA or missing values.  I've going to avoid bit64 just to not have to deal with this...

Comment: Thank you. I don't really *need* (or use) integers that large and was not aware of the limitation. Guess I won't be using bit64 until this is addressed, in my case NAs are much more frequent than large integers. For the record, `DT[as.character(V8)== "9218868437227407266"]` also returns the rows with the large value (i.e. the NAs). Also, `DT[as.character(V8)== "9218868437227407266", V8 := as.integer64(NA)]` seems to do the job.

Answer (score 7):

This bug, [#488](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/488), is now fixed with [this commit](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/a71e21d1f0e8e0134c8daf581ee6d328fef18f5b) in development version of data.table `v1.9.5`, and values are assigned (and displayed) properly as `NA` if `bit64` is loaded.

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.5
require(bit64)
ans = fread("test.csv")
#      V1  V2 V3 V4 V5  V6 V7         V8         V9        V10 V11
# 1: 2012 276 NA  0 S1 001  1         NA  724135215 1590915056  NA
# 2: 2012 276  2  8 S1 001  1         NA         NA     154598   0
# 3: 2012 276  2 12 S1 001  1         NA    5118863   21819477  NA
# 4: 2012 276  2  0 S1 011  8 3127133583 3127133583 9003982501   0
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing and following up here as well as on github.

Comment: This is still an issue in some cases and remains unresolved (I wouldn't now if hasn't just happened to me ;) ). https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1459