# Write data.table syntax as its dplyr equivalent to fix 9218868437227407266's integer64

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I have the `integer64` issue that instead of `NA` it shows `9218868437227407266` as it's described here: [fread() fails with missing values in integer64 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21627741/fread-fails-with-missing-values-in-integer64-columns)

I have loaded `bit64` package that with `data.table 1.9.5` or greater supposedly displays `NAs` instead of `9218868437227407266s` but it doesn't work. The issue is described here and is a `bit64` issue: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/488

I wrote this as a "solution":

```
dt[as.character(my_col) == "9218868437227407266", my_col := as.integer64(NA)]
```

It works but I wonder how I can write that in dplyr syntax to use the `%>%` without unexpected crashes.

Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `replace`

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
   mutate(my_col = replace(my_col, as.character(my_col) == "9218868437227407266",
                         as.integer64(NA))
```

Comment: after testing newer `data.table` versions the problem remains, and the pipeline hangs the system in cases where there is plenty of free memory